# Python Suds soap client for WCF. WS-reliable messageing

Tags: python, soap, wcf-client, ws-reliablemessaging

I have WCF service which uses WS-reliable messaging. I would like to write some python scripts that connect to this service using suds soap client but it seems that suds doesn't support reliable messaging out of the box. Does anybody tried to use suds with reliable messaging? Do I have to write some logic for handshaking like CreateSequence,TerminateSequece and so on? Or maybe there are another python soap clients which support WS-reliable messageing?

Thanks in advance.